# После перезапуска Сервисов местоположения перестает работать LocationListener

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api, gps, android-location

Использую данный код:

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
boolean IS_NETWORK_POVIDER_ENABLED = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
boolean IS_GPS_PROVIDER_ENABLED = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

if (IS_GPS_PROVIDER_ENABLED){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GPS enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1, 1, locationListener);
}

if (IS_NETWORK_POVIDER_ENABLED) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NETWORK enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1, 1, locationListener);
}

LocationListener locationListener = new android.location.LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        LatLng newMyCoord = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

        if (myPos != null)
            myPos.remove();
        myPos = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(newMyCoord));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(newMyCoord, 18));

        speed = (int) (location.getSpeed()*3600) / 1000;
        speedView.setText(String.valueOf(speed) + " " + "km/h");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

    }
};
```

Поначалу все работает хорошо, даже замечательно. Но стоит выключить и включить местоположение - ничего не работает. Маркер не двигается, спид не меняется.
Переустановка приложения не помогает. В чем проблема?

Пробовал запустить на другом устройстве - тоже самое. Все работает. Но стоит включить и выключить местоположение - все!
И независимо в какой момент это делаешь - при работающем приложении или нет...
Хэлп.